# AngularJS polling performance issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, performance

I'm working on a new app that uses Angularjs on the front-end.  The idea of the app is to poll/sync with server data every 5 seconds.  This is done in a service using $interval and an ajax call:

```
function beginSync() {
        if (!angular.isDefined(syncInterval)) {
            syncInterval = $interval(syncDetails, 5000);
        }
    }

    function endSync() {
        if (angular.isDefined(syncInterval)) {
            $interval.cancel(syncInterval);
            syncInterval = undefined;
        }
    }

    function syncDetails() {
        return $http({
            url: _contextPath + "/pathToAPI" + Id,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "RequestName": "Details Sync" }
        })
            .then(syncSuccess, syncFailure);
    }
```

The result of the sync will rePopulate an array objects, which in turn will update a nested ng-repeat.

```
function syncSuccess(response) {
        drives = angular.copy(response.data.drives);
        return response.data;
    }
```

In the controller I'm watching for the $destroy to remove the interval on page leave and such.

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
        SyncService.endSync();
    });
```

The problem is, after a few minutes of this, the page becomes slow and ultimately unresponsive.  I've tried debugging this using chrome tools, but am not that great at deciphering what it tells me.  Here is a link to the heap snapshots I took (1 with no polling, two while polling for a minute.) and the timeline view.
[Heap Snapshots](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ls3vp19exuo9yr3/AABOPB0EnbX5rc4cEGHhF4zSa?dl=0)

It seems to me there is event listeners not being destroyed somewhere in the dom when those elements are removed.  We aren't using any other jquery plugins or anything so I don't know why that would be the case.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is `beginSync` called?

Comment: Presumably you have an `ng-repeat` over `drives` somewhere? Does that contain any directives? The code you have copied is okay, I expect the problem lies within whatever gets generated by the `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Sounds like `beginSync` is being called repeatedly somehow. SHould be easy to see if requests are going out more often than 5 seconds and keep increasing frequency

Comment: beginSync is being called from the controller simply as a ng-click from a button to start the polling process.  And there are no directives implemented in the project yet.  And requests are definitely only coming every 5 seconds.

Comment: try using `$timeout` called inside `syncSuccess` instead of using interval. Allows for full cycle to complete.

Comment: @charlietfl that is definitely a smart idea, thank you.  But I still have this issue.

Comment: you have issues that are hard for us to debug based on what is known